# Sonar scan reports issue in Regex

Tags: java, regex, sonarqube, denial-of-service

This line of code in java is reported by sonar scan as a Security hotspot risk under Denial of Service (DoS) category.

```
name.matches("^.*[^a-zA-Z0-9 \\\\].*$")
```

How can I fix this? Is there an option to write this regular expression as a Java function?

Comment: Yes, this is a bad pattern. Just use `Matcher.find()` with `"[^a-zA-Z0-9 \\\\]"` regex string.

Comment: Unfortunately your app sonarqube there searches for `.*` or `.*?` before and after and declares it a catastrophic backtracking candidate. In reality having a single non-complex subterm in the middle (like `[^a-zA-Z0-9 \\]` does not cause any regex engine to backtrack more than once if `.*`, none if `.*?`. In essence leading `.*` terms start at the end of a string and backtrack once. If it doesn't find it it never gets to the trailing `.*`. If I were you I'd report this bug. Pass/Fail : 127,000 characters (40ms), no backtracking : https://regex101.com/r/mza1SF/1 https://regex101.com/r/JX0pHo/1

Comment: Please disregard that listed Duplicate as it is highly inaccurate.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your response. So in conclusion Sonar should not have reported this as an issue?